# Check if the index exists or not Elasticsearch

Tags: php, indexing, elasticsearch

I want to check in elasticsearch if the index exists or not. If it not exists it should create the index and do other functionality. I try to find out a solution for that, but did not find any perfect solution for that. Can anyone have any solution to solve this problem.

I am using Elasticsearch library.

```
**$client = new Elasticsearch\Client();**
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As per [index operations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/de7c2694a9d63a8f21cdda5a286aacc901fb42f9/docs/index-operations.asciidoc) and [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/de7c2694a9d63a8f21cdda5a286aacc901fb42f9/src/Elasticsearch/Endpoints/Indices/Alias/Exists.php) the following should work

```
 $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
 $indexParams['index']  = 'my_index';   
 $client->indices()->exists($indexParams);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that with later versions of elastic (I'm on 7.6) the user that is accessing ES needs the privilege of `view_index_metadata`. If using Kibana, you access these options via the Index privileges section of `management/security/roles` and then assign the roles to the user via `management/security/users`

Comment: `$client->indices()->exists($indexParams);` will return true or false

Answer (score 5):

This will return true or false:

```
$params = ['index' => 'products'];
$bool=$client->indices()->exists($params);
```

Comment: True or false or 1 or 0?

Answer (score 5):

For more recent versions of Elasticsearch (8.x), using the php library (with corresponding version 8.x) a call to `$client->indices()->exists($indexParams)` no longer returns a boolean, it instead returns an instance of `Elastic\Elasticsearch\Response\Elasticsearch`. This response is actually a 200 HTTP response if the index exists, or a HTTP 404 if it does not, but it also has the helpful `asBool()` you can use that abstracts away the HTTP codes e.g.

```
$client->indices()->exists($indexParams)->asBool();
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for list all indexes here:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_list_all_indexes.html

Using curl:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

Comment: i can't use localhost in my application, that is why i am searching other solution ...

Answer (score 2):

Other way by using Facade:

```sh
use ScoutElastic\Facades\ElasticClient;

$indexParams['index']  = "model_index";
$exists = ElasticClient::indices()->exists($indexParams);
if ($exists) {
   //do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with node.js, as below

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({
  node: ES_URL,
});
await client.indices.exists({ index: 'INDEX_NAME' });
```

and the response should be similar to this one below:

```
{
  body: true,
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    date: 'Sun, 07 Mar 2021 13:07:31 GMT',
    server: 'Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'content-length': '2796',
    'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100',
    connection: 'Keep-Alive'
  },
  meta: {
    context: null,
    request: { params: [Object], options: {}, id: 1 },
    name: 'elasticsearch-js',
    connection: {
      url: 'ES_URL',
      id: 'ES_ID',
      headers: {},
      deadCount: 0,
      resurrectTimeout: 0,
      _openRequests: 0,
      status: 'alive',
      roles: [Object]
    },
    attempts: 0,
    aborted: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Question is not about js, is about php. Almost question show client of Elasticsearch API PHP.