# Elasticsearch & PHP: Check if document exists before indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the PHP client to check if the user's input already exists before indexing it.

I have read some similar posts (like [Check Elasticsearch document similarity before indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633799/check-elasticsearch-document-similarity-before-indexing) or [Check if the index exists or not Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123992/check-if-the-index-exists-or-not-elasticsearch/31124288#31124288)) but they do not cover how to achieve this.

I tried to use `$client->search` and `$client->index` but I get the following error on the `$client->search` line:

> HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:129"}]...

Here is the code I tried:

```
   <?php
   require_once 'app/init.php';


    if(!empty($_POST)) {
      //Determines if the variables are set
      if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['thema'], $_POST['type'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $thema = explode(',', $_POST['thema']);
        $type = $_POST['type'];

        $searched = $client->search([
          'index' => 'my_index',
          'type' => 'default',
          'body' => [
            'query' => [
              'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                  [ 'match_phrase' => [ 'Title' => $title ] ],
                  [ 'match_phrase' => [ 'Description' => $description ] ],
                  [ 'match_phrase' => [ 'Thema' => $thema ] ],
                  [ 'match_phrase' => [ 'Type' => $type ] ],
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]);
        if($searched['hits']['total'] >= 1) { 
         print_r("Your idea already exists in the database");
        } 
       else {
        $indexed = $client->index([
          'index' => 'january-2018',
          'type' => 'default',
          'body' => [
            'Titel' => $titel,
            'Beschreibung' => $beschreibung,
            'Thema' => $thema,
            'Beitragstyp' => $beitragstyp
          ]
        ]);
       print_r("Your idea has been successfully submitted! The ID for your submission is: " . $indexed['_id']);        

      }
    }

    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Add | ES</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="text2">
        <h1>Matching</h1>
        <h2>Add your idea:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" class="addTerm" placeholder="Titel" name="title" required>
          <select id="themas" name="thema" required>
            <option value="thema1">thema1</option>
            <option value="thema2">thema2</option>
          </select>
          <select id="themas" name="type" required>
            <option value="type1">type1</option>
            <option value="type2">type2</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" class="addButton" value="Add &#xf067;" required>
          <textarea class="addBeschreibung" name="description" placeholder="Beschreibung" maxlength="2000" required></textarea>
          <button type="button" class="homeButton" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/server/elasticsearch-php/'">
            Home
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
```

Comment: $thema is an array and match_phrase should be a string : 'match_phrase' => [ 'Thema' => $thema ] ]

Comment: What is the difference with the one I have posted above? Can you give me some more details please?

Comment: Regarding error you getting. Your $thema variable is an array. Can not put array in match_phrase query. You should use combination of "bool" and "should", something like this: `"bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "Thema": $thema[0]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "Thema": $thema[1]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }` ...